# Ubuntu - Unable to find window provider error - Kivy

Tags: python, ubuntu, window, kivy

I'm sorry for duplicate, but I'm desperate. I' trying to run Kivy 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 18.10 with Python 3.6.8. This is the code I'running this code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/mangodile/.kivy          /logs/kivy_19-05-30_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (default, Apr  9 2019, 04:59:38) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 94, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:2204)

x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/utils.py", line 513, in __get__
 retval = self.func(inst)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
 EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
 sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I tried installing dependencies listed [on Kivy website](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html). I installed SDL2 -dev dependencies. I even tried installing pygame. Trust me, I searched a lot, but so far no luck.

Comment: You are using an old Kivy version 1.9.1. Try upgrading to the latest stable version 1.10.1.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install python3-kivy` upgraded Kivy to 1.11.0 and it works now.